# Run wcf service from IIS 7.5 with HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have created simple wcf service. After hosting the same at IIS 7.5. I am able to access the wcf service with HTTP , but I want to access the service using HTTPS.

Example :
http://myservice.publicservice/MyPublicService.svc?wsdl 
is accessible if I browse from IIS.

but
https://myservice.publicservice/MyPublicService.svc?wsdl 
is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable https binding in IIS. right click on the site where your service is hosted and there should  be an option "Edit Bindings". Use that to add an https binding

Comment: Under Default Web Site , there are multiple applications and my service is also hosted there.
So can you please elaborate the steps, how can I enable https ?

Comment: try to right click on your site, Managed Application -> Advance Settings -> Behavior (Enable Protocols) , see if setting HTTPS helps

Comment: I have been trying to check if there is a way to enable https binding to an application under a site. It seems you need to enable https at the site level and which would enable it for your application but the flip side is that it would open it for other applications as well.